# Why use sleep in loop(while or for var i)

Tags: php, apache

I have a long polling in php, is recommended use sleep(x seconds)? If i don't use, the PC will be slow? (Lagging, apache stop, etc). Have a difference?

Comment: could be the best idea, could be the worst - simply not enough information to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sleep` - of *any* duration, even "0 seconds" - is a quick way to get the Operating System's [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) to 'pause' the current task and allow another process to continue work.

This context switch prevents visible 'lagging' because the other processes have a chance to do what they need to do. Even if there is no other process that needs to do work a sleep still causes the current process execution to halt until it is rescheduled. The rescheduling alone this greatly prevents making the CPU a toaster because the effective/relevant time the process is given to work is greatly reduced.

Without the sleep (or other blocking IO task) it becomes a 'hot busy loop'; this loop is executed as fast as it can be and, even though the process will eventually be be [preempted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) without a sleep, the 'busy loop' will consume significantly more CPU resources before it is rescheduled. (This also implies that the same amount of work will take longer to complete when sleeping often.)

Thus: Sleep can be advantageous on *selectively* yielding work *in a CPU-bound application*; but at the same time it can reduce the CPU/processing throughput available if called too often or for too long. Sleeping in a loop has much less impact on an IO-bound application; in which case it's primary purpose is to impose longer delays before continuing a certain action.